# Access form methods and variables from a class and vice versa in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

I am trying to finds a way to have access to methods and variables of a form and a class from each other using instance. Here is my code:

My form code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int var1 = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Glob glob = new Glob(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

and my class code is:

```
public class Glob
{
    private Form1 _form;

    public Glob(Form1 parent)
    {
        _form = parent;
    }

    public int Func1()
    {
        return 10;
        _form.var1 = 10;
    }
}
```

I can call form methods from my class, but I can not call class methods from `button1_Click` event! What is wrong with my code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your scope for `glob` is local to your constructor.  Declare it as a module level variable and it will work just fine.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int var1 = 0;
    Glob glob;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        glob = new Glob(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        glob.Func1();
    }
}
```

[Edit]

Simon Whitehead's answer gives more detail of the other problems you have, but mine addresses your specific question of "Why can't I call `glob` from my button click?"

Answer (score 2):

This will never set the property:

```
public int Func1()
{
    return 10;
    _form.var1 = 10;
}
```

The function returns before the property is set. You should be getting an `unreachable code` warning.

Also, your `var1` variable is private. You need to make it public (capitalize it too). This is so it can be accessed outside of where its declared:

```
public int Var1 { get; set; }
```

In addition.. you want your `Glob` instance to be form level:

```
private Glob _glob;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _glob = new Glob(this);
}
```

Then you can call it in the click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _glob.Func1();
}
```